# git difftool runs git diff

Tags: git, difftool

I am obviously overlooking something very simple here, but I am not seeing it.  The command

```
webstorm diff ~/test.txt ~/test2.txt
```

runs the JetBrains graphical diff tool.  I am running git 1.8.3.2 and have a git .config that includes

```
[diff]
    tool = webstorm
[difftool "webstorm"]
    cmd = webstorm diff $(cd $(dirname "$LOCAL") && pwd)/$(basename "$LOCAL") $(cd $(dirname "$REMOTE") && pwd)/$(basename "$REMOTE")
[difftool]
    prompt = false
```

and when I run the command

```
git difftool ~/test.txt ~/test2.txt
```

I get the following in the terminal window:

```
diff --git a/home/mark/test.txt b/home/mark/test2.txt
index 7379ce2..6ce16f1 100644
--- a/home/mark/test.txt
+++ b/home/mark/test2.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-blah
+bluergh
```

What am I doing wrong / not doing?

Comment: Maybe you need to pass the absolute path to `webstorm`?

Comment: The webstorm folder is in the PATH

Comment: I understand that it's already in your path, but have you tried using an absolute path instead?

Comment: I have now, and I added a path to the [difftool "webstorm"] section.  I also renamed that section in case I had the same problem as http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/13188 - still nothing (apart from running it direct from the command line) working

Comment: Same problem here.. my config file is set to use meld, which is in my path.  when I run: git difftool, git runs "diff".  I added a section to my config like the below (to specify the full path to meld, but that didn't help).  This config snippet is the same in my global config file ($HOME/.gitconfig) as well as my project-specific config file.
>>
>> [difftool "meld"]
>>>> path = /usr/bin/meld
>> [diff]
>>> tool = meld

Answer (score 4):

Run:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git difftool --tool-help
```

to print a list of diff tools that may be used with `--tool`, and which are not available.

---

Secondly I believe the following simplified example may work better:

```
[difftool "webstorm"]
  cmd = webstorm diff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

Or by specifying the path to the binary or script, e.g.

```
[difftool]
  prompt = NO
  external = /usr/local/bin/diffmerge
```

---

Check the diff configuration by:

```
git config --get-regex diff
```

Or more specifically (replace `webstorm` with your tool name):

```
git config --get difftool.webstorm.cmd
```

---

If still doesn't work, test it on the new repository, e.g. by following these commands:

```
mkdir ~/git_test && cd ~/git_test
git init && touch file && git add file && git commit -m'Adds file' -a
echo changed >> file
GIT_TRACE=1 git difftool
```

If above works, then make sure your repository config doesn't have anything unexpected, e.g.

```
more "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/.git/config
```

---

If you're in merge state (check by `git status`), you need to use `mergetool` instead, e.g.

```
git mergetool
```

<sup>Add `-t tool` to specify which tool. List available by `git mergetool --tool-help`.</sup>

---

See also `man git-difftool`:

```
CONFIG VARIABLES
       git difftool falls back to git mergetool config variables when the difftool equivalents have not been
       defined.

       diff.tool
           The default diff tool to use.

       diff.guitool
           The default diff tool to use when --gui is specified.

       difftool.<tool>.path
           Override the path for the given tool. This is useful in case your tool is not in the PATH.

       difftool.<tool>.cmd
           Specify the command to invoke the specified diff tool.

           See the --tool=<tool> option above for more details.

       difftool.prompt
           Prompt before each invocation of the diff tool.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. My `git diftool` configuration has been set up in my `~/.gitconfig` and has been working fine, but today weirdly `git difftool` worked in one repo but ran `git diff` in another.

*Fix:* I updated from git 2.11.0 to git 2.11.1 and the problem seems to have gone away.

The [git 2.11.1 release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.11.1/Documentation/RelNotes/2.11.1.txt) mention fixing a difftool-related regression. The described problem isn't what I was seeing, but maybe the fix fixed it anyway.