# External git difftool is not working on windows

Tags: windows, git, diff, meld, p4merge

I'm struggling with git for many ours and have read almost all topics taged by "git", "diff" etc. and tried hundred of different solutions, but did not succeeded at all. I'm trying to set sum external difftool (Meld, p4merge) as my git tool, BUT git ignoring this option at all.
Here is my git config **--global**.

```
[alias]
    st = status
    co = checkout
    ci = commit
[diff]
    tool = p4merge
[difftool "p4merge"]
    cmd = p4merge.exe $LOCAL $REMOTE
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[merge]
    tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    cmd = p4merge.exe $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
    trustExitCode = false
    keepBackup = false
```

Mergetool command is working perfectly, but difftool is ignored and git starts always build-in diff. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're in merge mode (e.g. `.git/MERGE_MODE` file exists or check by `git status`), then you cannot use `difftool`, because the arguments are different, so you've to use `mergetool`.

If you'd like to abort the merge, run: `git merge --abort`, then `difftool` should work.

See also: [git difftool runs git diff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23855212/55075).