# git difftool not working (ubuntu)

Tags: git, vimdiff, difftool

When running git difftool --tool=vimdiff the output I get is a diff, what I want is vimdiff... If I use git diff I get a  `diff | less`

I try configuring the global setting:

```
git config --global diff.tool vimdiff
```

the local setting, adding the following into .git/config of the local repo

```
[diff]
tool = vimdiff
```

changing git version (currently `git version 2.11.0` and before `git version 2.7.4`)

Plus, I have the following doing `which vimdiff`:

```
/usr/bin/vimdiff
```

And running git difftool --tool-help

```
    'git difftool --tool=<tool>' may be set to one of the following:
            araxis
            gvimdiff
            gvimdiff2
            gvimdiff3
            vimdiff
            vimdiff2
            ...
```

It seems I am not the only one but I found no solution, any idea? 
( [git difftool runs git diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855212/git-difftool-runs-git-diff) and [Git difftool not opening sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642530/git-difftool-not-opening-sometimes), [External git difftool is not working on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623163/external-git-difftool-is-not-working-on-windows))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad question... It seems that after a `git stash pop` a conflict appears... I still don't get why git difftool was not working but once the files were merged, difftool (with vimdiff) starts working again.

Comment: FYI I just answered an older similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42314578/1056941) (my search turned that one up before this).  In my case the fix was just to update to git v2.11.1

Answer (score 1):

If you're in conflicted state, use `git mergetool` instead of `git difftool`, e.g.

```
git mergetool -t vimdiff
```