# Git difftool not opening sometimes

Tags: git, meld, difftool

I have 2 folders (with different code) with git initialized. But when I do

```
git difftool -t meld
```

one repo is working fine and asking me if I want to open files in meld to compare. The other one just output everything in the console and didn't execute meld.

Also both .git/config file is the same (except for the url)

Does anyone know why is that?

Comment: Please check repository configuration in .git/config

Answer (score 6):

If in one repository you're in conflicted state (check by `git status`), you need to use `mergetool` instead, e.g.

```
git mergetool -t meld
```

Related: [git difftool runs git diff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23855212/55075).

Answer (score 2):

You may have configured your `diff.tool` locally instead of globally (inspect the content of `.git/config` files in both your porjects, and your global `~/.gitconfig` file).

To set meld as your global difftool :

```
git config --global diff.tool meld
```

Comment: yes I am sure I have configured it globally.. I'll see if I can make a sample repo that difftool fails later.

Answer (score 1):

Meld will not launch if you are trying to check differences between two git branches, but there are no any actual code differences between them.

If this happened to you, just switch to another branch and try again, or make a small change of code and then try again.

Hope this saves someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have configured `difftool`, but not `mergetool`, and had a conflict outstanding?

I found similar behaviour, when I had an existing conflict that needed resolving. I think what happened to me was that git was trying to be 'helpful' and launch `mergetool` when I asked for `difftool`. I had not set up any `mergetool`, only `difftool`. When I manually resolved the conflict with `git add`, `difftool` started working again. Very frustrating.